# Custom route for activeadmin actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm making a page with activeadmin to update password of current user. I have a non-persisted model to check validation of password, etc. My problem is that when I try

```
ActiveAdmin.register UpdatePassword do
    actions :edit, :update
end
```

It creates the routes /update_passwords/:id and /update_passwords/:id/edit.

I want to change those routes to /update_passwords via get and put.

Is there any way to change that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do it with activeadmin but defining the routes manually worked:

```
#config/routes.rb
match "/admin/update_passwords" => 'admin/update_passwords#edit', via: :get, as: "admin_update_passwords"
match "/admin/update_passwords" => 'admin/update_passwords#update', via: :post
```

Answer (score 4):

Though the question is about 2 years old, but you can achieve routing as well as the customized method using `collection_action` or `member_action`. [Refer this](http://activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html).

Comment: The doc doesn't said how to put constraint on the show page. let's say, normally that resource is viewed by id. Now, i want to be able to view by his email, so i need to put more constraint. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the controller name UpdatePassword is confusing.

The paths end up being something like:

```
edit_admin_update_passwords_path
update_admin_update_passwords_path
```

I think that this would be better:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Password do
  actions :edit, :update
end
```

or

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  actions :edit, :update
end
```