# period in id in url creates issue with active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

```
#routes.rb

resources :users ,  :constraints => { :id => /[^\/]+/ }

namespace :admin do
  resources :users ,  :constraints => { :id => /[^\/]+/ }
end
```

when I call a route `/users/abc.efg` it works

but for `/admin/users/abc.efg` it does not

Lib Versions:

activeadmin (0.5.0)

rails 3.2

Comment: Outside of activeadmin you can do it by changing the id constraints (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5369702/776723); some activeadmin routes can be modified manually (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371161/custom-route-for-activeadmin-actions), but I haven't figured out how to manually change the id constraints.

Comment: In my case it turned out that all I needed to do was put my constrained routes before `ActiveAdmin.routes(self)`.  My routes are written a bit differently than yours, so I'm not sure the same will apply.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37125713

Answer (score -1):

I urge you to abandon the idea of using dot on url. Often the part after dot is regarded as `:format` in route, you may fight with the convention all the day.